# Android how to add transparent gradient to imageview

Tags: java, android, colors

I have an android app where I need to change all of the drawables in a listview. I have a custom adapter where I can change the color of any drawable to white. I then want to add a dissolve like (photoshop blending option) transparent effect to the drawable. I attached the images below to explain graphically (I used blue because it would be easier to see).

Original Image: Original green Android icon

Change Color: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mrs1152hvn2d25/step%201.png

Final: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvtp4q30jjxgd4e/final.png

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit? How would LayerDrawable do what i am looking to achieve?

Comment: oops, it was to comment the other question, but btw i cannot see any way how you could get the final image based on two first images - solid green and solid blue android icon